# How to remove a selected option from another select tag when i have five select with same options and values?

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>

    <select name="bonus<?php echo $i;?>" style="margin-top:30px;">

        <?php foreach($bonusable as $bns) {?>

            <option value="<?php echo $bns['type'];?>"><?php echo $bns['name'];?></option>

        <?php } ?>

    </select>

<?php }?>
```

This code display the five select and these have same options with the same value , and i need to delete the option if is selected in another select tag..  I have an image that shows what this code displays

[image: Here is the picture how to display]

please help me, and sorry for my English!

Comment: If I understand what you're getting at, you want to do that with Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: Ok, it does not matter but how can I do with javascript?

Comment: You mean if you delete the first select box option value "demo1" . Other select boxes also removed the option value "demo1" right?

Comment: @VinothRaja, no when i select in first box option value demo1 , in the other remove or disabled the option, for exemple in this picture you can't select two VIT case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
     <select id="bonus<?php echo $i;?>" name="bonus<?php echo $i;?>" onchange="Process_form('<?php echo $i;?>',this.value)" style="margin-top:30px;" >
                <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <?php }?>
</div>



<script>

function Process_form(Id,Value)
{

    <?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>

        var i='<?php echo $i; ?>';      

        if(i!=Id)
        {
            $("#bonus"+i+" option[value="+Value+"]").attr('disabled','disabled');

        }
    <?php } ?>

}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, sir.. i found a problem in this code if the option is selected others is disabled but if you need change in another option the option remain disabled , is not a big problem but i need to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for this.. i tried everything but this give me an error when i click submit:
Undefined index: bonus1 ..

```
   <script>
      var $select = $("select");
      $select.on("change", function() {
      var selected = [];  
       $.each($select, function(index, select) {           
          if (select.value !== "") { selected.push(select.value); }
                                    });         
            $("option").prop("disabled", false);         
                                   for (var index in selected) { $('option[value="'+selected[index]+'"]').prop("disabled", true); }
                                });
</script>
```